# Can i customize add/edit page for list in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

Can use my custom page to add/Edit item from sharepoint list?
if yes how? Do i need to do any config changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can! Check [Create a custom list](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101191111033.aspx) article form from Microsoft site. You will use SharePoint Designer 2007 for all the customizations. It also allows you to convert every form to HTML/XSLT and to customize it even further.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Designer, create a new ASPX Page then go to Insert => SharePoint Controls => List Form or Form Web Part and play around to see if it fits your needs.